# Join type (inner, left) and data type casting influences query plan, and order of operations

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join, common-table-expression, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create or replace table test.bugs.table_one as (
  select *, random(1337) as cost
  from (
    values 
      ('', '2010-01-01', 'one')
      , ('10', '2010-01-01', 'two')
      , ('11', '2010-01-01', 'three')
      , ('12', '2010-01-01', 'four')
    )
);

create or replace table test.bugs.table_two as (
  select *, random(1337) as budget
  from (
    values 
      (9, '2010-01-01', 'one')
      , (10, '2010-01-01', 'two')
    )
);

with 
  t1 as (
    select 
      column1::int as column1
      , column2
      , column3
      , cost
    from table_one
    where column1 !=''
  ),
  t2 as (
    select
      column1
      , column2
      , column3
      , budget
    from table_two
  )
select *
from t1
inner join t2
  on t1.column1 = t2.column1
  and t1.column2 = t2.column2
  and t1.column3 = t2.column3;
```

Returns: `3 rows`

Changing the join type to `INNER` results in error: `Numeric value '' is not recognized`. Instead of `::int` I ended up using `try_to_number()` function, but it took a bit of trial and error to figure out (query above is simplified, mine was more convoluted).

Is this a bug, or am I doing something odd?

Comment: `try_cast(t1.column1 as INTEGER)` is also working.

Answer (score 4):

Databases do not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.  In some databases, your code would always work.  In others, it might work sometimes and fail other times.

Is this a bug?  I consider it a bug, but clearly some database vendors do not.  You have found the work around.  Another method would be a `case` expression:

```
select (case when column1 regexp '^[0-9]+$' then column1::int end)
```

This should work, because `case` should guarantee the order of evaluation of its arguments.

Comment: A while ago submitted this original issue, to Snowflake, they agreed it was wrong, but wanted it to remain for performance reasons. I agree CASE works, but had to recently submit an issue for COALESCE that was effectively the same class of bug.

Answer (score 0):

When the join because an inner join things done before or after the join are equal. So things like cast can get hoisted.

The `WHERE` clause is supposed to evaluate before the SELECT section of t1 CTE.

I just retested by bug submition code, and now the broken case works, but the working case (with the correct TRY_TO_NUMBER fails).

I have queries like your that worked, and then once an extra layer of select around the outside was run with an aggregation over the results, the cast was hoisted back to the error state.

But yes, it's a bug, so I would report it.